# Apply VBA script, to format cells, to multiple rows and cells

Tags: excel, vba

I managed to get this code:

```vb
Sub ColorChange()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(2)

clrOrange = 39423
clrWhite = RGB(255, 255, 255)

If ws.Range("D19").Value = "1" And ws.Range("E19").Value = "1" Then
    ws.Range("D19", "E19").Interior.Color = clrOrange
ElseIf ws.Range("D19").Value = "0" Or ws.Range("E19").Value = "0" Then
    ws.Range("D19", "E19").Interior.Color = clrWhite
End If

End Sub
```

This works, but now I need this code to work in 50 rows and 314 cells, but every time only on two cells so, D19+E19, D20+E20, etc. Endpoint is DB314+DC314.
Is there a way, without needing to copy paste this code and replacing all the row and cells by hand?

It also would be nice that if the value in the two cells is anything other than 1+1 the cell color changes back to white.

EDIT: The solution thanks to @VBasic2008.
I added the following to the sheet's code to get the solution to work automatically:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D19:DC314")) Is Nothing Then
    Call ColorChange
End If
End Sub
```

And because Interior.Color removes borders I added the following sub:

```vb
Sub vba_borders()

Dim iRange As Range
Dim iCells As Range

Set iRange = Range("D19:DC67,D70:DC86,D89:DC124,D127:DC176,D179:DC212,D215:DC252,D255:DC291,D294:DC314")

For Each iCells In iRange
    iCells.BorderAround _
      LineStyle:=xlContinuous, _
      Weight:=xlThin
Next iCells

End Sub
```

The Range is a bit different to exclude some rows.

Comment: You can achieve this via conditional formatting. No need for VBA here?

Comment: i tried that but couldn't find one suitable for the thing i want. Which one should i use in your opinion?

Comment: `Home | Conditional Formatting | Use a Formula`

Comment: Ok found a solution to use conditional formatting, but now i need to apply it to all the rows and cells i need it to work in.

Comment: Select the enitre range to apply the formatting. Give it a try and if you are stuck then post what you tried and we will take it from there?

Comment: I edited my question, when i select a bigger range it just changes the color of every cell when there's a duplicate value of 1. I need it to only change if the value's are the same in the cells next to eachother i.e D19+E19, D20+E20, F19+G19, etc

Comment: See my 2nd comment. You have to use a formula

Comment: OK i get that but does that mean i should manually add it like this: =$D$19:$E$19=$D$20:$E$20 etc etc ?

Comment: No. Try this... (*Doing this from memory*).  

**1.** In the `Name Box` type, `D19:DC314` and press enter. This will select the relevant range 
**2.** Click on Home | Conditional formatting | new Rule | Use a Formula...
**3.** Enter 1st condition as `=AND(D19=1,E19=1)`
**4.** Select the orange color by clicking on the format condition
**5.** Similarly add a 2nd condition and change color to White

Comment: Will you be doing this for 'column pairs', e.g. `D:E`, `F:G`, `H:I`... or not, e.g. `D:E`, `E:F`, `F:G`...?

Comment: The formula doesn't work, if i do it like you said i get a 'there's a problem with your formula'-error. I found this: =AND($A1="Y",OR($B1="Email",$B1="Text")) in another question so tried: =AND($D19="1", $E19="1") and got the same message. @VBasic2008 Column pairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Compare Values in the Two Cells of Column Pairs

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ColorChange()
    
    Const rgAddress As String = "D19:DC314"
    Const Orange As Long = 39423
    Const White As Long = 16777215
    
    Dim wb As Workbook ' (Source) Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    Dim rg As Range ' (Source) Range
    Set rg = wb.Worksheets(2).Range(rgAddress) ' Rather use tab name ("Sheet2").

    Dim cCount As Long ' Columns Count
    cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim brg As Range ' Built Range
    Dim rrg As Range ' Row Range
    Dim crg As Range ' Two-Cell Range
    Dim j As Long ' (Source)/Row Range Columns Counter
    
    For Each rrg In rg.Rows
        For j = 2 To cCount Step 2
            Set crg = rrg.Cells(j - 1).Resize(, 2)
            If crg.Cells(1).Value = 1 And crg.Cells(2).Value = 1 Then
                If brg Is Nothing Then
                    Set brg = crg
                Else
                    Set brg = Union(brg, crg)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next rrg
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rg.Interior.Color = White
    If Not brg Is Nothing Then
        brg.Interior.Color = Orange
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot for taking your time to make this. I don't have a clue about how and why but, this works! I only had to add the Private Sub Worksheet_Change to the specific sheet to call the Colorchange for it to auto work. Is this normall?

Comment: That's it. You could improve with a solution to check odd and even columns for each cell that gets changed, but if the code isn't slowing down your worksheet considerably, you don't have to.